# C++Builder 2006: no more program icon if a .rc file is compiled

Tags: c++, c++builder, embedded-resource, c++builder-2006

I've added an .ICO file in the project options as usual, but since i added a .rc file (to embed a manifest) to the project, the program icon is no more embedded in the exe.
I tried to put the same icon in the Form "icon" property and it is visible, but still no icon is visible for the .exe file in Explorer.

How could i solve this?

Comment: Crystal ball says that your .rc file does not have an ICON directive.  Add one.

Comment: Can I ask also why? Is a .rc file completly replacing or removing the .res file compiled by default by the IDE?

Comment: @FabioCalzolari it can, if the .rc file has the same base filename as the default .res file. Custom resources should be compiled into their own .res file. Never put custom resources in the project's default .res file.

Comment: @Remy No, the project name is "MyApp_Setup", the.rc file is "MyApp_Setup1.rc", containing:   `1 24 "MyApp_Setup.exe.manifest"`